# Programming environment recommendation for (very) tight requirements

Tags: discussion, support

How do I ask about that?
I'm looking for some programming environment which:

1. is capable into bit-packed structures (bit-fields up to 32 bits in size)
2. has endianess abstraction, so I can follow BE documentation and run on LE

Above is important, I'd like to **maintain structure definitions instead of serializing/deserializing code**.

Comment: did you check [meta guidance](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487) referred in [comments](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/292017/programming-environments-capable-into-big-endian-bitfields-on-little-endian-mach#comment605431_292017) to your question at main siste? There's a section called: "Is there a place where I can ask such questions?"

Comment: There are many programming environments/languages that have these capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

This is a resource request and is [off-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site.

For more information, please see [Why was my question closed or down voted?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6487/) The short version is any such recommendations are one-off to a specific time and person, while the site is trying to be a repository of knowledge useful to *many* people and for the future as well. No question can truly be 100% future-proof. However, development environment tools and versions change constantly, making them an especially poor fit for the Q&A format.